# Box-Shadow Not Working in IE 10

Tags: css

I am having problems getting box-shadow to work in IE10 I have tried to add

`@media screen and (min-width:0\0)`

rule but with no success.
The codes works well in **firefox** and **chrome**.

code

```
.glossy-curved-black .slide-wrapper {
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 10px solid #FFF;
    box-shadow: 40px 40px 40px #000;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 40px 40px 40px #000;
   -moz-box-shadow: 40px 40px 40px #000;  
}

    @media screen and (min-width:0\0) {
    /* IE9 and IE10 rule sets go here */
      .glossy-curved-black .slide-wrapper {
         box-shadow: 0px 0px 80px #000;
       }
    }
```

my website [here](http://prelleyewear.com/)

Comment: is there a reason you're trying to use different CSS for IE9 and 10? At this point you should treat all browsers the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in your head element:

```
<!-- Mimic Internet Explorer 7 -->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

You're forcing the page into IE7 mode, if you want IE to act like a modern browser use `IE=EDGE` instead. I tested forcing the latest rendering mode and the shadow shows up.

## Update

Per recommendation by Microsoft, just use an HTML5 doctype and avoid sending a document compatibility mode. Browser detection is deprecated and should be avoided in general. Use feature detection instead. The default mode is an in standards mode always has been `EDGE`*.

```
<!doctype html>
```

*Except in the [web-browser control](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23690072/332733), in which case the document mode **must** be set explicitly to `EDGE` either via the `X-UA-Compatible` header or via the registry.

Answer (score 1):

The main CSS declaration without the vendor prefix should always be last. Try this instead:

```
.glossy-curved-black .slide-wrapper {
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 10px solid #FFF;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 40px 40px 40px #000;
   -moz-box-shadow: 40px 40px 40px #000;
   -ms-box-shadow: 40px 40px 40px #000;
   box-shadow: 40px 40px 40px #000;  
}

@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
/* IE9 and IE10 rule sets go here */
  .glossy-curved-black .slide-wrapper {
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 80px #000;
      -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 80px #000;
      -ms-box-shadow: 0px 0px 80px #000;
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 80px #000;
   }
}
```

I also noticed you had a weird min-width value in your media query. I have set this to 500px as an example for you.

Comment: The odd min-width media query is a hack for targeting IE 9&10:  http://blog.keithclark.co.uk/moving-ie-specific-css-into-media-blocks/